# How can I skip redundant Ansible handlers?

Tags: ansible, ansible-handlers

Imagine the following playbook, which manages a systemd service unit and a configuration file for a "thing" service:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - copy:
      src: thing.service
      dest: /etc/systemd/system/thing.service
    notify: restart thing

  - copy:
      src: thing.conf
      dest: /etc/thing.conf
    notify: reload thing

  handlers:
  - name: restart thing
    systemd:
      name: thing
      state: restarted

  - name: reload thing
    systemd:
      name: thing
      state: reloaded # Unnecessary if the restart handler has triggered.
```

If I modify the thing.service file AND the thing.conf file the handlers will trigger a restart AND a reload.

The reload is not necessary because the service will have been restarted.

Is there any way to inform Ansible of this so that it doesn't trigger the unnecessary reload after the restart?

I don't want to register variables and check those in the handlers with "when" clauses. I'm asking if this is something that Ansible accommodates in its playbook and task syntax.